# Copying a folder from Google Drive to Google Drive

Tags: file-management, google-drive, folder-organizer, folders

How do I copy a folder in Google Drive for Android or Google Drive via Google Chrome for Android?

I tried long pressing the folder but I cannot select the folders. I can only open them and view their contents.

Answer (score 3):

**It is not (yet) possible to copy and paste a folder on Google Drive.**

The [Google Drive Help - Organize your files in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375091#zippy=%2Cmake-a-copy-of-a-file) for "Computer" mentions the following regarding copying:

> #### Make a copy of a file
>
> **Important:**
>
> - [...]
> - You can’t copy folders, only files.
> - [...]

Thus, it has to be done manually:

1. Create a new folder and input a name
2. Navigate to the folder *to be copied*
3. Select one or more files to copy
4. Select "Send a copy"
5. Choose the "Drive" app
6. For "Location", navigate to *the new folder* and select it
7. Tap "Save"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my post. Can you please help me determine what the problem might be? Thanks.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson that looks like a different issue. I don't see the WiFi icon on the status bar, only mobile data. If you want to allow uploading files on mobile data, there's a setting inside the Google Drive app that states "Transfer files only over Wi-Fi".